# Conditionally add attributes to components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, flatlist

I have a flatlist where i want to add columnWrapperStyle only if numColumns greater than 1 , else I am getting some error.I tried something like below

```
     <FlatList
              data={data}
              if(numColumns>1)
              {
                columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}
              }
            }
>
```

I searched and many telling to use states inside attribute..but i do not want attribute name itself.how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1

Creating the props outside:

```
const flatlistProps = numColumns > 1 ? { data, columnWrapperStyle : ...} : { data }

<Flatlist {...flatlistProps} />
```

#### Method 2

Conditional rendering:

```
{numCounts > 1 ? <Flatlist data={data} columnWrapperStyle={...} /> : <Flatlist data = {data} />}
```

Comment: what should be in ... of columnWrapperStyle : ... , I am getting error if i use my style there.

Comment: It should be: `{ justifyContent: "space-evenly" }` What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const renderFlatList = (data,newColumn)=>
{ if(newColumn > 1)
      return <FlatList
           data={data}
           columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly" }/>

return <FlatList data={data}/>
}
```

And use it same as bellow:

```
{renderFlatList(data,newColumn)}
```

Comment: this is working for multiple column flatlist, like I mentioned I get error that columnWrapperStyle not supported for multiple column.

Answer (score 1):

```
const flatListData = { data };
if(numColumns>1) {
  flatListData.columnWrapperStyle= { justifyContent: "space-evenly" };
}

return (
  <FlatList {...flatListData} />
);
```